# How to show local SVG image in Image component of react-native

Tags: react-native, svg

I am developing a react-native app. I have a bunch of SVG files locally in my project. I would like to use my custom component to render Text and SVG image.

Here is my custom component which is supposed to render a `Text` and a `Image` for static SVG file:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

export default MyComponent = ({svgFile, text}) => {
   return (<View style={styles.line}>
        <Image source={svgFile} />
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>)
}
```

In my screen I try to show several `MyComponent` each renders a specific SVG image:

```
<View>
          
   <MyComponent
      svgFile={require('../assets/images/tiger.svg')}
      text="tiger"
   />

   <MyComponent
      svgFile={require('../assets/images/elephant.svg')}
      text="elephant"
   />

   ...
</View>
```

But only text is shown, the image is not shown. How to show a SVG file with a `Image` component ?  I need to have it work on both Android and iOS.

Answer (score 1):

The `Image` component in React Native doesn't support SVG rendering. I would suggest utilizing [react-native-svg](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg) to render your SVGs in your custom component. Import your svg file into the component, and render it using `<SvgXml />`:

```
export default MyComponent = ({svgFile, text}) => {
   return (<View style={styles.line}>
        <SvgXml xml={svgFile} />
        <Text>{text}</Text>
      </View>)
}
```

Comment: Should I still use `{require('../assets/images/tiger.svg')}` to assign to `svgFile` ?

Comment: I just use import syntax: `import MySvg from ‘assets/my-svg.svg’`

Comment: After adding this `{
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "babel-plugin-inline-import",
      {
        "extensions": [".svg"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}` in `.babelrc` file.